# Oracle osuser - where is it specified in asp.net nHibernate?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, nhibernate

We have an asp.net web application that uses nHibernate with our Oracle backend DB. We have found out that in different environments (i.e. dev & produdtion), the osuser logged on Oracle having different values/strings. So where does Oracle grab the osuser from the asp.net application? Where can I look specifically to troubleshoot why the 2 values of osuser's being different? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `osuser` in `v$session` should be the operating system user that is running the middle tier application server (IIS).  If you are seeing different values in different environments, that implies that IIS is running as a different Windows user in the two environments.  That would be expected if your development environment is running IIS on your local laptop (likely as your Windows user) while the production environment is running IIS using a Windows domain account.